# let $f,g:\mathbb{I} \to \mathbb{I} $ continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

$\mathbb{I} = [0,1]$

let $f,g:\mathbb{I} \to \mathbb{I} $ continuous functions such that $ f \circ g = g \circ f$.
Prove that there is $ x_0 \in \mathbb{I}$ such that $ f(x_0) =g(x_0)$.

Could you help me by giving me an idea of ​​how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If no such $x_0$ exists, then (WLOG) $f(x)>g(x)$ for all $x$.

Let $x_0$ be a fixed point of $f$ (I believe you can show its existence using IVT).

Then $gx_0$ is also a fixed point of $f$:
$$
f(gx_0) = g(fx_0) = gx_0
$$
as are all iterates $g^Nx_0$
$$
f(g^Nx_0)=g^N(fx_0) = g^Nx_0.
$$
On the other hand since $f>g$,
$$
g^{N+1}x_0< g^Nx_0,
$$
(they form a decreasing sequence).

By compactness, $g^n x_0 \rightarrow x_g$ for some $x_g$. This $x_g$ is a fixed point of both $g$ and $f$, a contradiction.

Comment: could you explain what  is IVT?

Comment: Intermediate value theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem

Comment: Just an observation: Your assumption at the beginning also uses the IVT. About $f$ having a fixed-point: Use a similar argument to the one in the latter half of your answer.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice I used it twice. In fact, the existence of a fixed point for $f$ is the same argument as saying $f=g$ nowhere implies $f>g$ or $f<g$, applied with $g =$ identity.

Comment: thank, for your help i could do it. @user25959